# ¿Qué ha pasado con el diseño para versión móvil del sitio?

Tags: bug

No estoy seguro de si es un error en mi dispositivo o si es algún cambio realizado de forma global en el sitio.

Las fuentes usadas para el título de la pregunta son exageradamente grandes:

[image: Lista de preguntas]

Y la cosa se pone aún más divertida al entrar a cualquier pregunta:

[image: Título exageradamente grande en la pregunta]

¿Esto es a nivel global en el sitio? ¿Es un problema de mi dispositivo o navegador usado?

Por cierto, Samsung Galaxy S22, Android, Navegador `Brave 1.52.130, Chromium 114.0.5735.198`

Añado una foto de caché de cómo se veía antes:
[image: Vista antes del cambio en el diseño]

Comment: Yo uso comúnmente también el sitio móvil usando dispositivos Android e iOS, pero no tengo este problema, tal vez tienes alguna configuración que cambia el tamaño de la fuente. El navegador de donde realizó este comentario usa  Chromium 114.0.5735.196

Comment: A mí también me sucede en Chrome.

Comment: Me sucede lo mismo, uso iOS y Safari en móvil. Pero, en la computadora, me sale el sitio correctamente.

Comment: Confirmo que me pasó lo mismo

Comment: @DanteS. Al parecer la actualización a lo largo de toda la red ha tardado bastante. Seguiremos esperando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal parece que este “error” fue algo que afectó a toda la red. Investigando, en la comunidad en inglés sucedió lo mismo.

Pueden ver [esta pregunta de Meta en StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425716/increased-font-size-on-mobile-browsers) donde un staff asegura que se ha arreglado este error.

Le he comentado esto de igual manera debido a que aún no se ha solucionado el error en nuestra comunidad.

Además parece que no somos la única comunidad que aún experimenta este error. Previamente entré a *Spanish Language* y este inconveniente se sigue presentando. Sin embargo, en otras a las que pertenezco y he entrado, esto no sucede.

La explicación oficial fue esta

> This was due to a change to some `font-size` values to replace explicit pixel values with calculated values based on custom properties. To be honest, I'm not sure why the calculated values cause this issue and explicit pixel values don't. Nevertheless, changing back to explicit pixel values resolves the issue.
>
> ---
>
> Esto se debió a un cambio en algunos valores de "tamaño de fuente" para reemplazar valores de píxeles explícitos con valores calculados basados en propiedades personalizadas. Para ser honesto, no estoy seguro de por qué los valores calculados causan este problema y los valores de píxeles explícitos no. Sin embargo, volver a cambiar a valores de píxeles explícitos resuelve el problema.

**Resolución** El staff me ha mencionado que este caso será programado para ser resuelto internamente y es cuestión de tiempo a que se borre el caché del CSS que estaba ocasionando este problema, pero que la petición para que esto pase tardará un poco. Mencionó que puede tardar hasta mañana.